# BST golang search func

Tags: go, binary-search-tree

can you help with search func, it always returns nil and i cannot understand why

```
func BTreeSearchItem(root *TreeNode, elem string) *TreeNode {
    if root == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if root.Data < elem {
        return BTreeSearchItem(root.Left, elem)
    } else if root.Data > elem {
        return BTreeSearchItem(root.Right, elem)
    }
    return root
}
```

Tried to do like this, but it returns 4 instead of 7

```
func BTreeSearchItem(root *TreeNode, elem string) *TreeNode {
    if root == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if root.Data < elem {
        BTreeSearchItem(root.Left, elem)
    } else if root.Data > elem {
        BTreeSearchItem(root.Right, elem)
    }
    return root
}
```

Complete Code is

```
package main

import "fmt"

type TreeNode struct {
    Left, Right, Parent *TreeNode
    Data                string
}

func BTreeSearchItem(root *TreeNode, elem string) *TreeNode {
    if root == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if root.Data < elem {
        BTreeSearchItem(root.Left, elem)
    } else if root.Data > elem {
        BTreeSearchItem(root.Right, elem)
    }
    return root
}

func BTreeInsertData(root *TreeNode, data string) *TreeNode {
    if root == nil {
        return &TreeNode{Data: data}
    }
    if root.Data == data {
        return nil
    }
    if root.Data > data {
        if root.Left == nil {
            root.Left = &TreeNode{Data: data}
        }
        return BTreeInsertData(root.Left, data)
    }
    if root.Data < data {
        if root.Right == nil {
            root.Right = &TreeNode{Data: data}
        }
        return BTreeInsertData(root.Right, data)
    }
    return root
}

func main() {
    root := &TreeNode{Data: "4"}
    BTreeInsertData(root, "1")
    BTreeInsertData(root, "7")
    BTreeInsertData(root, "5")
    selected := BTreeSearchItem(root, "7")
    fmt.Print("Item selected -> ")
    if selected != nil {
        fmt.Println(selected.Data)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("nil")
    }

    fmt.Print("Parent of selected item -> ")
    if selected.Parent != nil {
        fmt.Println(selected.Parent.Data)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("nil")
    }

    fmt.Print("Left child of selected item -> ")
    if selected.Left != nil {
        fmt.Println(selected.Left.Data)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("nil")
    }

    fmt.Print("Right child of selected item -> ")
    if selected.Right != nil {
        fmt.Println(selected.Right.Data)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("nil")
    }
}
```

searched the internet and found a lot by methods, but i need as func. i'm beginner at programming, so it hard to me to understand

[PlayGoundLink](https://play.golang.org/p/0WcpyJcJ-tI)

Comment: Your `BTreeInsertData` function is pretty badly wrong as it stands. It never sets any `Parent` (so why does the `Parent` pointer exist?) and it returns a new or modified `*TreeNode` which no caller actually saves anywhere. I made a [fairly simple repair](https://play.golang.org/p/ZepOZ338Yow) that at least lets the program run, but it still never sets `Parent`, and its `BTreeSearchItem` is still pretty badly wrong—it only ever returns either `root` or the constant `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is check the value of `root` in `main()` before calling function `BTreeSearchItem`. What I suspect is `root` values is already `nil` in that stage itself.

Comment: you mean piscine? sorry, my bad, forgot to delet it

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/0WcpyJcJ-tI main func and BTreeInsertData should work fine

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/7EpPchuLs3U did this, and got this output 
```&{0xc0000a6360 0xc0000a6390 <nil> 4}
&{0xc0000a63c0 <nil> <nil> 7}
&{<nil> <nil> <nil> 1}
Item selected -> 4
Parent of selected item -> nil
Left child of selected item -> 1
Right child of selected item -> 7
 ```

Answer (score 0):

okey, https://play.golang.org/p/gQmdYLfAvIY this code works, in `BTreeInsertData` forgot to add `Parant` and in `BTreeSearchItem` I mismatch `Right` and `Left`